# Does Project Lombok contradict the data encapsulation of using a getter and setter?

Tags: java, validation, lombok

Declaring a private variable and accessing it through the public getter/setter method (the encapsulation principle in Java) can be utilised to add custom validations in the setter method.

For Eg: If I put a negative number validation in my `setBalance()` setter method in `Bank` Class, I can restrict negative amount deposition in the `Bank`. That means accidental changes in the fields can be restricted. So if I am using lombok, obviously I don't need to define getter/setter method. What can I possibly do to incorporate the above mentioned validation.
Wouldn't it restrict leveraging the data encapsulation property of Java?

Comment: Validation has nothing to do with encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

By using `@Getter`, `@Setter`, `@Data` or `@Value` [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) is auto-generating a public accessor to your field, **if you don't need to expose fields** you can use `AccessLevel.NONE` on `@Getter`, `@Setter`.
[Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) can be respected using lombok.

I would suggest you to consider data structures and actions that can be performed on them (like validations) as separate concerns. In this way you will be able to modify data and validations separately.
To achieve that you can use some framework like [spring](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aop_with_spring.htm) or [aspectj](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

If you feel that approach is overkill for your application, you can resort to immutable data structures (`@Value`) with private constructors and static methods used to create the instance. Those methods will perform the necessary validations.

Another method to add validation on your class could be by using annotations on the getters using [hibernate validation](http://hibernate.org/validator/).

Comment: But from the quoted wiki link , it says : "Encapsulation, in object-oriented programming, is the bundling of data with the methods that operate on that data, or the **restricting of direct access to some of an object's components.**". But using @Setter , all the field in an object can be directly accessed ......

Comment: @KenChan Lombok generated getters and setter only if you told to do so.
I was talking about something you need to expose... If you don't need to expose things you can override the behaviour by using `AccessLevel.NONE`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: cool , so it should be when using @Setter ,  lombok only not generate setter for a field only if you told to do so as by default it will generate for all fields

Comment: Depends on your needs. You can avoid using `@Data` and only using `@Getter` for the only field you need to expose, **if** you need to expose anything at all. You can use lombok only to generate equality comparison if you want. You don't need to un-default all the fields of a class. And thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are right. So you should use it carefully depending on the context.

If an object is a rich domain object , simply use `@Setter` to add public setters for all its fields is probably a bad idea as the client can easily set any fields to any values without invoking the proper method which encapsulate all the business logic that should be done. So in the end , the object 's state may be incorrect.

But if the object is just serve as a data container which does not have any business logic (e.g DTO), using `@Setter`/ `@Getter` can save you some times and make the codes has less noise.

Comment: It's not that simple.  Lombok doesn't, and never will, support [defensive copies](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2655).  See CERT vulnerability [OBJ05-J] (https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/OBJ05-J.+Do+not+return+references+to+private+mutable+class+members) as one example.  There are CWE violations related to this shortcoming as well.

Comment: @user6629913 i cannot get how your comment has anything related to encapsulation that we are talking about

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't break data encapsulation, it makes it more convenient: simple getters and setters are just noise.

If your code requires something other than a simple get or set then obviously generating them automatically doesn't make sense--but that's an orthogonal issue: you wouldn't be able to do it manually either.

You're conflating restricted access with business logic.

In any case: you *might* be able to use an AOP system to put guard clauses around automatically-generated functions, but you'd need to enforce the order the processors run in. IMO that's a recipe for confusion and an additional cognitive overhead: keep business logic either explicit, or layered on top of explicit code.

Comment: there is a very specific reason getters and setters were needed, _before_ there were "tools" that would use them. It is the only way to "react" to changes made to a certain field. anyway, java is on a path to fix this and cut the verbosity away with "datum" classes, at least this was the name when I last looked at the feature proposal.

Comment: @Eugene I'm not sure what you're responding to, but ok.